# Помогите с окном tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

Хочу сделать точно такое же окно в tkinter (но без иконки), но не знаю как выровнить кнопки, добавить текст.

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def display_full_name():
    messagebox.showinfo("Имя пользователя + пароль", name.get() + " " + surname.get())

root = Tk()
root.title("Вас приветствует Windows")

name = StringVar()
surname = StringVar()

name_label = Label(text="Имя пользователя:")
surname_label = Label(text="Пароль:")

name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
surname_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

name_entry = Entry(textvariable=name)
surname_entry = Entry(textvariable=surname)

name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=3)
surname_entry.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=3)


message_button = Button(text="Отмена", command=display_full_name)
message_button.grid(row=1,column=2, padx=5, pady=3, sticky="e")

message_button = Button(text="ОК", command=display_full_name)
message_button.grid(row=0,column=2, padx=10, pady=3, sticky="e")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Мне нужна помощь, я не знаю как добавить в тот код текст и как выровнить там кнопки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы разместить объекты в сетке (`grid`) удобно сначала нарисовать саму сетку поверх интерфейса:
[image: Сетка]

Текст добавляете как объект `Label`, точно так же как подписи к текстовым полям. Размещаете в нужной строке (`row`) и колонке (`column`). Т.к. текст занимает по вертикали и горизонтали больше одной ячейки, при размещении нужно через параметры `rowspan` и `columnspan` указать сколько ячеек в высоту и в ширину это поле занимает:

```
info = Label(text="Для входа...\n(Переключение раскладки ....)", justify=LEFT)  # выравнивание текста по левому краю
info.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=2, sticky="nw")  # nw - прилипание виджета к северо-западу (влево вверх)
```

Дальше у остальных объектов исправляете номер колонки и строки, где они должны размещаться:

```
name_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
surname_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")

...

name_entry.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=3)
surname_entry.grid(row=3,column=1, padx=5, pady=3)
```

У кнопок также делаете отступы одинаковыми (`padx=5`) и прилипание к границам ячейки одновременно влево (**w**est - запад) и вправо (**e**ast - восток), чтобы кнопки стали одинакового размера:

```
ok_button = Button(text="ОК", command=display_full_name)
ok_button.grid(row=0,column=2, padx=5, pady=3, sticky="we")

cancel_button = Button(text="Отмена", command=display_full_name)
cancel_button.grid(row=1,column=2, padx=5, pady=3, sticky="we")
```

Что должно получиться:
[image: Результат]