# Как сделать такую программу с помощью Entry, Radiobutton, Button, Label в Tkinter(Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать такую программу с помощью Radiobutton, Button, Entry, Label в Tkinter(Python).

```
from tkinter import *

def first_label():
    label['text'] = 'НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО'
def second_label():
    label['text'] = 'НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО'
def third_label():
    if entry_ == "правильно":
        label['text'] = 'ПРАВИЛЬНО'
    else:
        label['text'] = 'НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО'

root = Tk()
root.geometry("350x120")
label1 = Label(root, text="Выберите верный вариант написания слов в русском языке")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

var = IntVar()
var.set(0)
Radiobutton(text="пастолку, пасколку", command=first_label,
            variable=var, value=0).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
Radiobutton(text="вилька, тарелька", command=second_label,
            variable=var, value=1).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W")
Radiobutton(text="ваша версия", command=third_label,
            variable=var, value=2).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")

entry_ = StringVar()
 
a_entry = Entry(textvariable=entry_)
a_entry.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c")
a_button = Button(text="Проверить", command=third_label)
a_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

label = Label(width=20, height=2)
label.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Как должно выглядеть в результате:

[image: описание изображения]

Как выглядит сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вот же у вас программа с Radiobutton, Button, Entry, Label. Вопрос в чем?

Comment: он не так работает как на заданий

Comment: там внизу есть фото

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкратце: не используйте place. В 99% случаев его можно заменить на `grid` или `pack`.

Чтобы правильно разместить с помощью `grid`, удобно расчертить интерфейс сеткой, пронумеровать столбцы и строки, посмотреть где должны быть объединенные ячейки, в соответствии с этим разместить элементы управления. Пример с подробным разбором можете посмотреть в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1180520/1365

Более-менее исправленный код:

```
from tkinter import *

def first_label():
    label['text'] = 'НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО'
def second_label():
    label['text'] = 'НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО'
def third_label():
    if entry_.get() == "правильно":  # Для получения текста из StringVar нужно использовать метод .get()
        label['text'] = 'ПРАВИЛЬНО'
    else:
        label['text'] = 'НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО'

root = Tk()
# root.geometry("350x120")  # Не ограничиваем размер, чтобы текст не обрезался
label1 = Label(root, text="Выберите верный вариант написания слов в русском языке")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

var = IntVar()
var.set(0)
Radiobutton(text="пастолку, пасколку", command=first_label,
            variable=var, value=0).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
Radiobutton(text="вилька, тарелька", command=second_label,
            variable=var, value=1).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W")
Radiobutton(text="ваша версия", command=third_label,
            variable=var, value=2).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")

entry_ = StringVar()
 
a_entry = Entry(textvariable=entry_)
a_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)  # Размещаем в той же строке, что и последний Radiobutton, но во второй колонке
a_button = Button(text="Проверить", command=third_label)
a_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)  # Размещаем на строке ниже чем последний Radibutton, в двух первых колонках

label = Label(width=20, height=2)
label.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если важно, чтобы текстовое поле было вплотную к переключателю, можно разместить их в общем фрейме, а этот фрейм уже разместить по сетке (только измененный код):

```
frame = Frame()
frame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")

Radiobutton(frame, text="ваша версия", command=third_label,  # Указываем frame как родительский элемент управления
            variable=var, value=2).pack(side=LEFT)

entry_ = StringVar()
 
a_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=entry_)  # Указываем frame как родительский элемент управления
a_entry.pack()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]